# copy C:\Dire\*.bak /d:%date% C:\Dire\D2\*.bak - Not working, has before somehow

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I tried

copy C:\Dirname*.txt /d:%date% C:\Dirname\Dirtwo*.txt

to move a file from a directory to it's sub-directory, but only a file that was created TODAY.

and I got it to work once, I don't remember the way I worded it and i've fooled with this for a little bit. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use "xcopy" for options like /d